# Different between two date(kotlin)

Tags: android, date

I have two date like this
current date 2019-10-09
birthday date 2000-01-01

How can I recognize, that currentdate - birthdaydate will be more than 18 years ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android difference between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate someone's age in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question:

[Finding days difference between dates in Android Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288195/finding-days-difference-between-dates-in-android-kotlin).

Can easily be modified to get the year difference between dates.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

fun main(args : Array<String>) {

    val start = "2019-05-24 14:17:00"
    val end = "2019-09-13 14:15:51"

    daysBetweenDates(start, end)
}


fun daysBetweenDates(start: String, end: String) {

    val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    val mStart = LocalDateTime.parse(start, format)
    val mEnd = LocalDateTime.parse(end, format)

    val difference = ChronoUnit.Years.between(mStart, mEnd)

    println("START => $mStart")
    println("END => $mEnd")
    println("DIFFERENCE => $difference in years"}
}
```

Comment: Using java.time is good advice. Why not use `ChronoUnit.YEARS` from the outset? Converting by hand is a bad habit, and dividing by 365 doesn’t give an accurate result.